# Get the link inside href selenium python

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I am trying to get the link href with python and selenium.
The href url is `<a target="_blank" href="https://click.discord.com/ls/click?upn=RANDOMNUMBERSANDLETTERS" style="text-decoration:none;line-height:100%;background:#5865f2;color:white;font-family:Ubuntu, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;font-size:15px;font-weight:normal;text-transform:none;margin:0px;"> Verify Email </a>`
I want to get the full discord link but I have no idea how, I tried looking for answers but all of them said element not found.

Comment: If you provide additional surrounding HTML, it might help form the basis of alternate answers.

Comment: https://prnt.sc/1uwigbq

Answer (score 2):

You can have a **web element** using **xpath**

```
//a[contains(text(),'Verify Email')]
```

and the call

```
get_attribute('href')
```

**sample code :**

```
link = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//a[contains(text(),'Verify Email')]").get_attribute('href')
print(link)
```

Comment: That worked, but is there any other way to do the same thing?

Comment: @Jarvn what part of this answer did you not like?

Comment: Well I tried out the code and I got the website's url instead of value in the href

Comment: @Jarvn : Then why did you comment this `That worked, but is there any other way to do the same thing? ` ? It's highly unlikely that you'd get a website url using get attribute method, there are different method to get the browser url.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
ele=driver.find_element_by_xpath("//a[contains(text(),'Verify Email')]")
ele.get_attribute('href')

print(ele)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also use css locators since xpaths should generally be used as a last resort (they can break easier and mess up your browser automation, they are just more brittle). As a very basic example css=#email (or whatever the id is called), If you want to use a tag with id the syntax is an example would be from what you posted above is css=a[href='linkText'].